# Starting activity from packageinfo

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way run an intent from packageinfo? I've been searching and I don't find it.

I tried like that

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(p.applicationInfo.packageName,p.applicationInfo.name));
startActivity(i);
```

but it doesn't work because `p.applicationInfo.name` is always null.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me using SDK 8.18

Assuming that "p" is your PackageInfo

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = p.applicationInfo;

String packageName = appInfo.packageName;

startIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

if(startIntent != null){
    startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use folowing code:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().p.applicationInfo.packageName(p.applicationInfo.packageName);
startActivity(i);
```

before start activity you may setup any flags (`i.setFlags()`), if you need.